# Why was my custom answer flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I custom-flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34264143/3479456) answer:

> This answer just restates what OP already knows. (maybe OP's question was edited after this answer was posted?)

And it got declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

While this answer has no technical inaccuracies, I would say that it is the wrong answer given that OP clearly knows how to search for basic patterns:

> I can search word in vim with `/word`.

Was the flag just rejected, because people are hesitant to remove such a popular answer, or did I wrongly flag it?

The last time I saw a comment like that was when I flagged an actual answer as "Not an Answer", but I have since [learned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) not to do that, and used the custom flag for this answer.

Comment: But the flag decline note specifically says that it *should not be used to indicate wrong answers*. So, saying "it is the wrong answer" is proving that the decline reason was correct... or am I missing part of your question?

Comment: *"The last time I saw a comment like that was when I flagged an actual answer as "Not an Answer", but I have since learned not to do that, and used the custom flag for this answer."* You must have been given really bad advice if you continue to want to flag things you should be downvoting.

Comment: @Catija huh, I guess I read it wrong... my bad. late night I guess...

Comment: @Gimby I didn't mean that I use the custom flag *instead of* "Not an Answer.  I do tend to downvote those answers. I meant that *in this case*, I chose to custom flag

Comment: @Catija Something I didn't explicitly state in my question is that I thought that that decline reason was only given when flagging an answer as "not an answer" and was surprised to see it for the custom flag, since I never said that it wasn't an answer, just a wrong answer. Is the rule that I shouldn't flag any answer if it's wrong (but properly formatted, well-presented, etc.)?

Comment: That decline reason is one of four default ones available to moderators at all times. One thing you might consider in future - you have a lot of room in your flag reason. Moderators (particularly on SO) get lots of flags, so being more clear in your flagging reasoning helps mods determine whether flags are valid or not.

Comment: @Catija Are you saying that there was something I could have said that wouldn't have gotten my flag declined (and if so, could you give me an example of that; I feel like I said everything that needed to be said in my custom flag). Or would you refrain from flagging an answer like this?

Comment: If you're looking at a highly-upvoted answer that you feel isn't an answer, it might be better to not flag, considering the answer you have here but if you're trying to understand why it's upvoted when it doesn't answer the question, you could bring attention to it here on meta, the way you have. There's also a lot of discussion of what qualifies as an "answer" at all and different moderators will interpret that differently. While only a moderator could delete that answer, many users seem to think that it does have value.

Answer (score 5):

[@Catija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4548692/catija) addressed the flagging question, but I wanted to make a more general point given the context you provided:

You should also consider that Stack Overflow, for better or worse, functions as a repository of coding knowledge. Answers are not necessarily bad *just* because they don't answer the OP's actual question. In your particular example this question is the first result when googling "searching for words in vim", and the answer you link to was given 6 years after the original question. I would imagine the answerer thought other people might find this question through a search engine, and wanted to provide a convenient answer to the title's question for future googlers. Given this context, I would not downvote on mismatch of question description and answer alone. After all, the ambiguous title is not the answerer's fault: the OP could have chosen a more descriptive title, or a reviewer could have edited one in.

Comment: So you don't downvote answers that don't answer the question, but are good answers for another question? Hmm. I guess the downvote arrow helptext says "This answer is not useful". Is that to be interpreted as "not useful in the context of this question (since it doesn't answer it)", or "not useful at all". Seems that you would prefer the latter interpretation. Second, you say, "the ambiguous title is not the answerer's fault". Well OK, but the answerer is presumably expected to read the question body and realize that the about-to-be-posted answer doesn't actually answer the question, right?

Comment: To be fair, you said, "given this context, I would not downvote...", so maybe it wasn't fair to say that you wouldn't downvote period. I'm curious, if this question and answer were just posted (both with a score of 0, say), would you downvote?

Comment: Regarding Catija's point, I must have misread the declined reason, so that's fair. Your point about how Googlers will come across this question and find that answer useful is an interesting one - I didn't really consider that. I'm still a bit on the fence about this though. Yes, it's a popular answer, and maybe we shouldn't remove it at this point, but it blatantly doesn't answer the question. Guess in the future, we should catch this sooner? (Regarding my initial question, I won't flag wrong answers in the future if that's the rule... thanks)