# A high-value answer was moderator-deleted without explanation as far as I can tell. What's the right thing to do?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

I was looking at a question about how to get [TFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) and Git to play well together with Visual Studio, and [noted a comment referring me to an answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154562/using-both-local-git-and-remote-tfs-with-visual-studio-2013/33787579?noredirect=1#comment109127853_33787579). It turns out it was a clever, high-value answer that fixed the issue of the original question.

More importantly, the old fixes listed in the answers to the original question no longer worked for the most recent versions of Visual Studio. That is, this comment is currently the only link to a viable answer to the question for users of recent version of Visual Studio.

Since the linked answer was a useful, creative fix for a problem whose earlier solutions no longer worked, [I recommended that the commenter add their answer to the question I was reading now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154562/using-both-local-git-and-remote-tfs-with-visual-studio-2013/33787579?noredirect=1#comment113101580_33787579).

Turns out [they had added it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154562/using-both-local-git-and-remote-tfs-with-visual-studio-2013/33787579?noredirect=1#comment113122002_33787579). And [it had been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61659016/1028230)!

What's the right thing to do here? Flag for intervention?

**Is there a way to see why the original moderator deleted the answer?** It is a *little* unorganized and narrative, which isn't ideal, but is an excellent answer to the issue at hand. I'd be happy to edit it if that's the issue. Maybe it's the `visual-studio-2013` tag and the implication is a new question should be asked?

Which leads me to... I'm surprised the moderator didn't put a comment on the answer before deleting (or if they did, the comment is deleted now). I suppose you might assume someone at around 3k (like the answer's author) knows Stack Overflow okay, so perhaps the moderator thought they should know better than to be this colloquial and narrative, but the answer's author, if I read into the comment a bit, seemed a little surprised it was deleted as well.

In any event, a good answer is missing. Should I do something to put it back?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the first sentence was the problem: *I'm also having problems with Git...* and second opening paragraph starts with *I have tried lots of different solutions, but none have worked* Sounds a bit like a question at a glance, leading to deletion. *What's the right thing to do?* Custom-flag: "Was this a mistake?" is what I'd do (were it not for the fact that this meta-discussion exists already)

Comment: The added answer was exactly the same content, without any hint or clarification that it was duplicated from somewhere else.

Comment: Honestly that entire answer reads as if it's a question on it's own. It is in need of a rewrite if it actually has useful information embedded in it.

Comment: *FYI:* I think [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400442/my-custom-flag-to-delete-an-answer-that-only-provides-redundant-insights-was-dec) post might interest you.

Comment: You have sufficient rep to see deleted posts, right? So you can capture the valuable information from the deleted answer in a new answer that is better written.

Comment: Also see [*Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227) on the Uber Meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It was deleted because it was duplicate answer and had been automatically flagged by the system.

If you can post exactly the same answer to two (or more) questions then there is a very good chance that the questions are duplicates. What you should be doing in such cases is answering the best question and then flagging/voting to close the other questions as duplicates. Stack Overflow works best when all the answers are in one place.

If the questions aren't duplicates then you should tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.

So, in this case you should be examining the questions and deciding whether they are duplicates or not. If they are vote to close the poorer question as a duplicate of the better one (the relative ages of the questions doesn't matter).

If the questions aren't duplicates then consider how the answer can be tailored to fit the second question, edit it and flag it to be undeleted.

Comment: But isn't it perfectly possible for two truly different questions to have the same answer? I don't have an example on hand (probably bad for my point) but I find it hard to conceive that all identical answers MUST stem from the same question. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Mixone I will concede that there *may* be some non-trivial questions where the answer is identical. However, I didn't say that the question *must* be duplicates, just that there was a good chance they were. If you do find one then please still tailor your answer to each question.

Comment: Yeah you do say must, I'm more thinking about the auto-flag, when it is auto-flagged does it still need to be "okayed" by a mod or is the answer auto-deleted?

Comment: @Mixone the auto flag has to be processed by a moderator.

Comment: @mixone *"But isn't it perfectly possible for two truly different questions to have the same answer?"* - in the grand scheme of things yes, but on Stack Overflow I don't expect to ever naturally run into such a situation. Technical Q&A which hammers on facts doesn't really lend itself to it.